# PHP/Regex How to get the value of this string?

Tags: php, regex

Hello I am pretty sure I can find someone who can solve this..

I am looking to get the value 'April 21, 2013' out of this string:

```
$string = "Issue Date: Sunday April 21, 2013 / week 10/2003week 11/2003week 12/2003week 13.."
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `|Issue Date: (.*?) /|` should work

Comment: I tried:
preg_match("#Issue Date: (.*)/#", $string, $matches);  and then explode the matches by space.. But that was a bad choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`preg_match()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with the following regex `/^Issue Date: [A-z]+ (.*) \//`:

```
// prepare string and pattern
$string = 'Issue Date: Sunday April 21, 2013 / week 10/2003week 11/2003week 12/2003week 13..';
$pattern = '/^Issue Date: [A-z]+ (.*) \//';

// exec regex and check for results
if(!preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)) {
    die('the pattern was not found');
}

// output the results:
$date = $matches[1];
echo $date; // output: 'April 21, 2013'
```

Comment: He said he wants to get `April 21, 2013` not `Sunday April 21, 2013`

Comment: Yep! I've realized this too. Check my update

Answer (score 2):

No need for regex:

```
$string = 'Issue Date: Sunday April 21, 2013 / week 10/2003week 11/2003week 12/2003week 13..';
$array = explode(' ',$string);
$date = $array[3] . ' ' . $array[4] . ' ' . $array[5];
echo $date;
```

Comment: @hek2mgl I'm not missing the comma

Comment: Dude I undid your edit because your edit created an output with 2 commas. Try code out before you criticize it...

Comment: Sorry! you are right, I see now. However I've not critized it, I've upvoted it and wanted to help

Comment: It's just a little annoying when someone who already put up an answer to a question edits another person's answer to make it give an incorrect output.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for whatever appears first (after "Issue Date: ") then this will work:

`Issue Date: (.*) /`